# jQuery: Enable submit button only if the user enters correct string format

Tags: jquery, regex

I want to disable a login button, and enable only if the user has input correct number format with regex. 
This is not about the Regex issue. My problem is about the jQuery code is not working.

Here is my code:

```
$('#username').keyup(function () {
    var gval = $('#username').val();
    var re = new RegExp("^\s*(\+?\d{1,3})0*\d{2}[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{3,4}\s*$");
    if (re.test(gval)) {
        $('#login-sms-btn').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $('#login-sms-btn').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

As I already apply disabled value to the button and hope to enable it when user input correct regex format. But it doesn't works.

Can anyone help to solve this please?

Comment: What is the correct format of your input?

Comment: My correct input format is something like this +88899123456

Comment: Why not just `\+\d{11}` ?

Comment: Yes thank you for the suggestion. But my problem actually is about my script doesn't work.

Comment: Inside a string literal, to define a backslash you need a double backslash. But you should use a simpler thing: a regex literal, `var re = /^\s*(\+?\d{1,3})0*\d{2}[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{3,4}\s*$/;`